# asp:DropDownList datasource is null after submit when declared inside an asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

I am using a DropDownList in an UpdatePanel. It fills when the user writes some text in the TextBox and click the "Go" Button.

xaml is as follow :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ODSearchTB" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="ODFindButton" 
            class="btn btn-default goButton"
            runat="server" Text="Go" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            UseSubmitBehavior="False" 
            CausesValidation="False" 
            OnClick="ODFindButton_Click" /><br/>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ODSearchDDL" runat="server" Visible="False"  AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind that fills the DropDownList on click :

```
protected void ODFindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var res = ServiceUnitOfWork.MedicalOffices.FindMedicalOfficesByName(
        ODSearchTB.Text,
        doctor: false,
        hospital: true,
        service: false,
        establishment: true);
    List<LightMedicalOffice> source = getLightMedicalOffices(res.ToList());

    ODSearchDDL.DataSource = source;
    ODSearchDDL.DataTextField = "Name";
    ODSearchDDL.DataValueField = "IdAddress";
    ODSearchDDL.DataBind();
    ODSearchDDL.Visible = true;
}
```

This works fine, the datasource will update properly and the DropDownList will be filled and updated (in the UpdatePanel) without the page reloading. The problem occurs when the form is submitted : the DropDownList is empty (datasource null) in the `Page_Load` event so when I reach the `Submit_Click` and the `CustomValidator_ServerValidate` events, I can't know what was the selected value of the list.

The ViewState seems to be enabled on both the page and the control. I have no clue to what could cause such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do you reset the DropDown in the Page_Load event?  I implemented your code above, and added a submit button outside of the update panel.  I was able to capture the value of the DropDown control within my OnClick event of the submit button.

Comment: No I don't. I4ve tried capturing the value at the first line of the Page_Load with `var val = dropdownlist.DataSource` and it is already null at this point right after the submit.

Comment: why are you trying to capture the DataSource?  What if you are capturing the value: ODSearchDDL.SelectedValue.

Comment: Well I've tried to capture any property of the dropDownList, It's empty and selectedvalue is "".